# Mysql - Check if id exists in foreign tables

Tags: mysql, foreign-key-relationship

I got a "big" database (10M rows), and I need to delete useless acquisition ids (which dont have acquisition_id relationship anymore).

Table *acquisitions* :

```
- id
- date
```

Table *datapres* :

```
- id
- value
- atmo
- #acquisition_id
```

Table *datatemps* :

```
- id
- #acquisition_id
```

Table *dataconds*:

```
- id
- value
- stack_num
- #acquisition_id
```

So I need to SELECT ALL Acquisition id withtout relationship in those 3 tables. Is it possible directly in SQL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use multiple `LEFT JOIN`s :

```
SELECT a.id
FROM acquisitions a
LEFT JOIN datapres dp
 ON(a.id = dp.acquisition_id)
LEFT JOIN datatemps dt
 ON(a.id = dt.acquisition_id)
LEFT JOIN dataconds dc
 ON(a.id = dc.acquisition_id)
WHERE dp.id IS NULL OR
      dt.id IS NULL OR
      dc.id IS NULL
```

This will bring you the `ID`s that are missing from one of the 3 data tables.

Comment: I tested the first selected acquisitions.id, but its not missing , finded in datapres.acquisition_id

Comment: You want it to return if it's missing from **all** tables or just **one** ?? @kesm0 , right now just one is enough, if you want all, then replace `OR` with `AND`

Comment: Yes I needed all tables, works perfectly ! Thank you